# Inserting disks in a container having different diameters at each level

Tags: c#

I need to make a program , in which the number of layers for a container and their diameters are taken input from the user. Then the user inserts a disk of certain diameter into the program. Then the disks moves through all possible layers , the process can be repeated until the container is filled or user stops adding more disks to it. Finally the program is supposed to give total number of disks contained in the container and their layer numbers.  Iam badly stuck and my mind is blank now. Kindly help!

[updated code] The problem remains that the container is never fills , program keeps on inserting disks. I cant think of a logical way to let it know when container is full.

```
  namespace ConsoleApplication1
  {
  class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Console.Write("Number of Layers ? ");
        int layers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] container = new int[layers];
        int disk_number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < layers; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\nLayer num {0} : ",1+i);
            container[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.Write("\nPress 1 to Insert disk? ");
        int insert = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (insert == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("\nDiameter of Disk? ");
            int disk_diameter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


           if (disk_diameter <= container[0])
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < layers;) {
                    if (disk_diameter <= container[i])
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    else { if (i == layers - 1) break; layers = i+1; }

                }

                disk_number++;

                Console.Write("\nPress 1 to Insert more disk(s)? ");
                insert = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (insert != 1) { Console.Write("\nNumber of disks contained in container are : {0}", disk_number); }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("\nDisc blocked the surface opening of the container , no further input could be processed! \nNumber of disks contained in container are : {0}",disk_number);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();



    }

    //static int inserting_disk(int a);
}
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What's not working, exactly? If we don't know, we can't really help you.

Comment: You may want to put in some error handling for user input that is not parsable by `int.Parse`.

Comment: While it's not clear to me what you are trying to do, there are some obvious oversights: first, there is the `layers_filled` variable which you test, but never set/modify.  Secondly, there's the `disk_placement` variable which you set/modify but never use.  It seems likely that these could be causing your problem.

Comment: @varocarbas Perhaps you meant something different, but SO is very much about algorithms and except for it's unclearness, this question is easily within the FAQ guidelines. (the unclearness is a problem though)

Comment: @RBarryYoung I didn't mean coming with the best algorithm (understood as "coding approach") to certain problem. I meant: asking for delivering a working algorithm for a more or less simple situation. This is not a problem which might accept different alternatives and might trigger a discussion regarding the best approach. This is a straightforward problem (although, which requires from various steps and thus from certain effort, which has to be performed by the OP) which might be accounted for by a simple loop and some arrays. This is what I meant: please, don't ask us to build your loops.

Comment: @varocarbas That is still well within the guidelines.  The OP has shown us their work, shows a basic understanding of the language (they have in fact coded the loops, though they may be incorrect) and their question cannot easily be answered with Google.  Even at the level of your criticism there are literally tens of thousands of such questions like that asked and answered here without a problem (and to be fair, I think that this question is slightly above that).

Comment: @RBarryYoung OK. I accept your critic and thus will delete my comment. But just to make my position clear: I am not saying that the OP hasn't shown effort and certain understanding of the situation (he surely did); just that what he wants to fix does not require any specific help other than just building the loop. I am saying all this in the OP's own interest: if you wrote this code, what is pending is really easy; just take a rest, do it by your own and learn from it.

Comment: @varocarbas
I am working on the problem , the main confusion lies within the loop only. I will get back , if all odds fail :)

Comment: I am happy to read that: firstly fighting and failing and fighting again and failing again (and perhaps crying a bit LOL)... and only where there is no clear way: asking. This is the best way to learn.

Comment: @varocarbas can you check the code and help now?

Comment: I see some improvement; still a bit off but I guess that I can help you a bit out (if I get what you want to do exactly, what I am not completely sure about). Write you back in a while.

Comment: As I guessed after a quick look: your code is pretty confusing (what you are doing and the name of the variables). This is what I understand that you want to do: to allow the user to input the number of layers (for example: 2); and then the maximum diameter allowed for each layer (for example: 10 and 20). Then you ask the user if he wants to add a new disk and your intention is checking all the layers (where you are stuck). My first impression was that you wanted to go through all the layers whose diameter is bigger than the diameter of the current disk (if any). But after looking at your

Comment: ... code a bit more, I am not so sure about this. Can you please confirm the EXACT functionality you are after? Take my description above and correct the bits you want.

Comment: You are right. You should the one taking care of the specific details. There you have my answer with a code delivering what I understood + various improvements in different parts of your codes (overall structure still pretty poor -> you should learn to use function and to account for non-expected input situations). I hope that you will find this helpful.

Comment: @varocarbas the main objective was to make a container that has user defined layers (with different user defined diameters) and then the user is supposed to add disk(s) untill he wishes to stop or the container is filled. Result would be to print the total disk(s) contained in the container

Comment: @varocarbas I know my programming is confusing , i am a noob after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained me what you want exactly, but here goes a much improved (on different fronts) version of your code which, hopefully, you will take as a good learning exercise. The overall structure is pretty bad, but I have intended to emulate the one in your original code such that you can understand perfectly what is going on. The "input flow" is still pretty poor and thus might stop working easily (if the right inputs are not introduced) but, at least, I have replaced your `Parse` with `TryParse` accounting for different-type inputs (e.g., a `string` instead of an `integer`).

Test the code, see what it does. Get used to the new variables (I have renamed/redefined some of them because were too confusing in its original version) and build a code delivering exactly what you are after (and, ideally, properly written).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Number of Layers ? ");
            int input0 = 0;
            bool right0 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input0);
            if (right0 && input0 > 0)
            {
                int tot_layers = input0;
                int[] maxDiamLayer = new int[tot_layers + 1]; //better maintain the indexing as displayed to the user: starting from 1
                bool[] layerDone = new bool[tot_layers + 1]; //This boolean array will make sure that you don't use the same layer more than once
                int disk_number = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= tot_layers; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\nIntroduce the maximum diameter for the layer num {0} : ", i);
                    maxDiamLayer[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.Write("\nPress 1 to Insert disk? ");
                input0 = 0;
                right0 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input0);

                while (right0 && input0 == 1)
                {

                    Console.Write("\nDiameter of Disk? ");
                    int input = 0;
                    bool right = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
                    if (!right || input <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nWrong Diameter. ");
                        continue;
                    }
                    int disk_diameter = input;

                    bool oneInserted = false;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= tot_layers; i++)
                    {
                        if (disk_diameter <= maxDiamLayer[i] && !layerDone[i])
                        {
                            layerDone[i] = true;
                            oneInserted = true;
                            disk_number++;
                            Console.Write("\nNumber of disks contained in container are : {0}", disk_number);
                            Console.Write("\nPress 1 to Insert more disk(s)? ");
                            int input2 = 0;
                            bool right2 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input2);
                            if (!right2 || input2 != 1 || disk_number >= tot_layers) break;

                            Console.Write("\nDiameter of Disk? ");
                            input = 0;
                            right = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
                            if (!right || input <= 0)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\nWrong Diameter. ");
                                break;
                            }
                            disk_diameter = input;
                        }
                    }

                    if (disk_number >= tot_layers)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nAll the layers are filled");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nWrong diameter. Try again.");
                    }

                    if (!oneInserted)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nThe disk couldn't be inserted");
                        Console.Write("\nPress 1 to continue ");
                        int input3 = 0;
                        bool right3 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input3);
                        if (!right3 || input3 != 1) break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine(); 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I am trying to get used to the conventions used by you and learn the most out of it.

Comment: @TahaRushain no problem. Just bear in mind that the conventions I included in this code are, in general, meant for an easier understanding. If you are more comfortable with how things were in your code, just use them.